# Пишу бота на Pythone, бот почему-то никак не откликается на текст, не могу понять почему

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def chto_hochesh_first(message):
  if message.chat.type == 'private':
    if message.text == 'ДЗ':
      third_choice = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
      fizika = types.KeyboardButton("Физика")
      math = types.KeyboardButton("Вышмат")
      history = types.KeyboardButton('История')
      rusk = types.KeyboardButton('Русский')
      vvp = types.KeyboardButton('ВВП')
      vvit = types.KeyboardButton('ВВИТ')
      inostr = types.KeyboardButton('Ин.яз.')
      exitt = types.KeyboardButton('Назад')

      third_choice.add(fizika, math, history, rusk, vvp, vvit, inostr, exitt)

      bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выбери предмет', reply_markup=third_choice)
    elif message.text == 'Лекции':

      second_choice = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
      fizikalec = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Физика лекции", callback_data='fizika')
      mathlec = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Вышмат лекции", callback_data='math')
      historylec = types.InlineKeyboardButton('История лекции', callback_data='history')
      rusklec = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Русский лекции', callback_data='rusk')
      vvplec = types.InlineKeyboardButton('ВВП лекции', callback_data='vvp')
      vvitlec = types.InlineKeyboardButton('ВВИТ лекции', callback_data='vvit')
      inostrlec = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Ин.яз. лекции', callback_data='inostr')
      exitt = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Назад', callback_data='exitt')

      second_choice.add(fizikalec, mathlec, historylec, rusklec, vvplec, vvitlec, inostrlec, exitt)

      bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выбери предмет', reply_markup=second_choice)
    elif message.text == 'Расписание':

      fourth_choice = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def chto_hochesh_second(message):
  if message.chat.type == 'private':
    if message.text == 'Физика':
      bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Достать учебник Савельева Общая физика какая-то там')
    elif message.text == 'Вышмат':
      bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Тут ДЗ')
    elif message.text == 'История':
      bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Тут ДЗ')
    elif message.text == 'Русский':
      bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Тут ДЗ')
    elif message.text == 'ВВП':
      bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Тут ДЗ')
    elif message.text == 'ВВИТ':
      bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Тут ДЗ')
    elif message.text == 'Ин.яз.':
      bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Тут ДЗ')
    elif message.text == 'Назад':
      first_choice = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
      dz = types.KeyboardButton('ДЗ')
      lections = types.KeyboardButton('Лекции')
      timetable = types.KeyboardButton('Расписание')

      first_choice.add(dz, lections, timetable)

      bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Назад'.format(message.from_user,bot.get_me()),parse_mode='html', reply_markup=first_choice)

bot.infinity_polling()
```

из функции chto_hochesh_second, когда боту поступает текст например "Физика", то он ничего не выводит, с остальным условием всё также не выводит, даже кнопку "Назад", не могу понять в чём проблема.

Comment: `бот почему-то никак не откликается на текст`, а на остальные действия он откликается или он в принципе не работает?

Comment: все функции что я до chto_hochesh_second писал работают

Comment: именно последняя функция отказывается работать и когда поступают сообщения с предметами или с текстом "Назад", то ничего не работает

Comment: так у вас оба хэндлера просто отлавливают текст и срабатывает только верхний

Comment: кстати, да...callback_data никто не обрабатывает. @ZxNuClear, оформите ответ - я вам плюсик поставлю)

Comment: как мне это исправить? @ZxNuClear

Comment: @vald3mar, обновил свой ответ. Код вероятнее всего можно "расчесать", но как передачу самой сути отображает, проверьте

Answer (score 0):

### UPD

С данной библиотекой особо не работал, но если "грязно", то как-то так:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def chto_hochesh_first(message):
  if message.chat.type == 'private':
    first_choice = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=3)
    dz = types.InlineKeyboardButton('ДЗ', callback_data='dz')
    lections = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Лекции', callback_data='lec')
    timetable = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Расписание', callback_data='rasp')
    first_choice.add(dz, lections, timetable)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Выбери тему'.format(message.from_user,bot.get_me()),parse_mode='html', reply_markup=first_choice)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_function1(call: telebot.types.CallbackQuery):
  if call.data == "dz":
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
    fizikadz = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Физика ДЗ", callback_data='fizikadz')
    mathdz = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Вышмат ДЗ", callback_data='mathdz')
    historydz = types.InlineKeyboardButton('История ДЗ', callback_data='historydz')
    ruskdz = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Русский ДЗ', callback_data='ruskdz')
    exit = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Назад', callback_data='exit')
    keyboard.add(fizikadz, mathdz, historydz, ruskdz, exit)
    bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text="Выбери предмет", reply_markup=keyboard)

  elif call.data == "lec":
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
    fizikalec = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Физика Лекции", callback_data='fizikalec')
    mathlec = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Вышмат Лекции", callback_data='mathlec')
    historylec = types.InlineKeyboardButton('История Лекции', callback_data='historylec')
    rusklec = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Русский Лекции', callback_data='rusklec')
    exit = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Назад', callback_data='exit')
    keyboard.add(fizikalec, mathlec, historylec, rusklec, exit)
    bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text="Выбери предмет", reply_markup=keyboard)

  elif call.data == "rasp":
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
    fizikarasp = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Физика Расписание", callback_data='fizikarasp')
    mathrasp = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Вышмат Расписание", callback_data='mathrasp')
    historyrasp = types.InlineKeyboardButton('История Расписание', callback_data='historyrasp')
    ruskrasp = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Русский Расписание', callback_data='ruskrasp')
    exit = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Назад', callback_data='exit')
    keyboard.add(fizikarasp, mathrasp, historyrasp, ruskrasp, exit)
    bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text="Выбери предмет", reply_markup=keyboard)

  elif call.data == "exit":
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=3)
    dz = types.InlineKeyboardButton('ДЗ', callback_data='dz')
    lections = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Лекции', callback_data='lec')
    timetable = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Расписание', callback_data='rasp')
    keyboard.add(dz, lections, timetable)
    bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text="Выбери тему", reply_markup=keyboard)

  elif call.data == "fizikadz":
    bot.delete_message(call.message.chat.id, call.message.id)
    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Тут Домашнее задание по Физике')
  elif call.data == "fizikalec":
    bot.delete_message(call.message.chat.id, call.message.id)
    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Тут Лекция по Физике')
  elif call.data == "fizikarasp":
    bot.delete_message(call.message.chat.id, call.message.id)
    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Тут Расписание по Физике')
  

  elif call.data == "mathdz":
    bot.delete_message(call.message.chat.id, call.message.id)
    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Тут Домашнее задание по Вышмату')
  elif call.data == "mathlec":
    bot.delete_message(call.message.chat.id, call.message.id)
    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Тут Лекция по Вышмату')
  elif call.data == "mathrasp":
    bot.delete_message(call.message.chat.id, call.message.id)
    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Тут Расписание по Вышмату')
  

  elif call.data == "historydz":
    bot.delete_message(call.message.chat.id, call.message.id)
    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Тут Домашнее задание по Истории')
  elif call.data == "historylec":
    bot.delete_message(call.message.chat.id, call.message.id)
    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Тут Лекция по Истории')
  elif call.data == "historyrasp":
    bot.delete_message(call.message.chat.id, call.message.id)
    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Тут Расписание по Истории')
  

  elif call.data == "ruskdz":
    bot.delete_message(call.message.chat.id, call.message.id)
    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Тут Домашнее задание по Русскому')
  elif call.data == "rusklec":
    bot.delete_message(call.message.chat.id, call.message.id)
    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Тут Лекция по Русскому')
  elif call.data == "ruskrasp":
    bot.delete_message(call.message.chat.id, call.message.id)
    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Тут Расписание по Русскому')
  
  bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id)

bot.infinity_polling()
```

Comment: а как же обработка callback? :_( https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI#callback-query-handler

Comment: @МихаилРебров вы про `@bot.callback_query_handler(text='ТЕКСТ')` вместо `@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])`?

Comment: да, хотя конкретно pyTelegramBotAPI я не пользовался...я больше на ноде и на java поддерживал и писал боты. Но насколько я понимаю это именно то, что нужно ТС

Comment: @МихаилРебров, я обновил свой ответ, если интересно - оцените, может есть предложения как сделать его чище? )))